How to get pitest-bdd to run a directory of .feature files against a single Python test script
Sorry i am new to to pytest-bdd and am having trouble finding resources on how to run a directory of .feature files against a single Python test script.
Example of one of these feature files:
Feature:
   Check if data parameter exists in column1 

Scenario: Example1
    
    Given <parameters>
    When SQL to execute:
    SELECT  
        column1 
    from table 
    where column1 = '%Data_Entity'
    
Examples:
    |parameters|
    |Data_Entity=parameter;|

